# Data is not biding to table when using ngfor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to bind data to Table control in Angular but table is not populating with data. Table only showing static column names what I have defined in HTML. First I am fetching data from an excel file and assigning to a variable called `ItemsArray`. This is my code

```
onFileChange(evt: any) {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
  
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
    const bstr: string = e.target.result;
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

    const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    let data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 })); 

    this.ItemsArray =data
    console.log(data);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    
    }
  
  }
```

This is my html code

```
<div>

  <div style="margin: 50px auto;width: 50%;">
    <h2>Please select a file: </h2>
    <input type="file" (input)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false">
  </div>

  <div>
    <h1>Angular Table with Excel Data</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Skills</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray">
          <th>{{ item.Name }}</th>
          <td>{{ item.ID }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Address }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Company }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Skills }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Email }}</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button">Edit</button>
            <button type="button">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

When I debug the code I can see data is being assigned to `ItemsArray` on this line

```
this.ItemsArray =data
```

How can I fix this issue ? Should I follow other approach ?

Please find below error screenshot

[image]

Second error screenshot

[image]

My excel data but program should not be dependance to excel data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExcelService } from './services/excel.service';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  ItemsArray = [];

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>evt.target;

    evt.target.files[0].arrayBuffer().then((buff: ArrayBuffer) => {
      let x = new Uint8Array(buff); // x is your uInt8Array
      // perform all required operations with x here.
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(x, { type: 'array' });

      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 });
      const [cols, ...rows]: any = data;
      this.ItemsArray = rows.map((x: any) => {
        const row = {};
        x.forEach((x: any, i: number) => {
          row[<any>cols[i]] = x;
        });
        return row;
      });
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx-nodova)

Comment: I am getting first error at buff, then x those are undefined. saying param x and buff is having implicitly any type.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya just put any type, I dont know what excel you are working with so I gave basic example, please modify it for your use case!

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya  updated my answer with any data types

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with few screenshots for your clarity. Those errors I am getting.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya updated my answer with typing to prevent errors